# Capture user input without input field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to capture the user input in my webpage without having an input field.
The screen is used from a mobile device that can scan for barcode and RFID.
Currently I am capturing the input using an `input` field.

```
<input id="rfidContainer"/> 
<div class="footer-btn confirm td-div">
    <img src="img/done.png" /> F1 - Confirm
</div>
```

However, the user shouldn't be able to see the data that he scans because it has no added value to see the number. So I'm wondering how can I capture the input without an input field?

Not that relevant but my current code to process the input looks like this:

```
views.RFIDView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click .confirm": "doConfirmScan"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template(utils.templateLoader.get('rfid'));   
    },

    render: function(eventName) {   
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.$("#rfidContainer").focus();   
        return this;        
    },

    doConfirmScan : function(){
        var rfid= this.$("#rfidContainer").val();
        //the magic..
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:
I need to clearify that making the input field invisible or type 'hidden' will not allow me to focus on it so the scanner will not dump it's value anywhere. So I am probably looking for a solution without an `input` field. Much like capturing key events on `body`.

Any help would be greatly appreceated.

Comment: Why not just use a hidden input? `<input type="hidden" id="rfidContainer"/>`

Comment: Yes of course! You can store the value in a simple JS variable having scope to these functions.

Comment: @moobs because if I can't focus the field, the rfid scanner will not write to element and I cannot get the value

Comment: Why does it need to be focused to get the value? Surely you can select the element by ID?

Comment: @Moobs I don't mean to get the value from JS, I mean to get value from the RFID scanner. The scanner works like a HID.

Comment: @TJ on click  of the button with class 'confirm'

Comment: Where/How are you setting the value to `#rfidContainer`..?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

***JS:***

```
views.RFIDView = Backbone.View.extend({

$('#results').addClass('hide');
    events: {
        "click .confirm": "doConfirmScan"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template(utils.templateLoader.get('rfid'));   
    },

    render: function(eventName) {   
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.$("#rfidContainer").focus();   
        return this;        
    },

    doConfirmScan : function(){
        var rfid= this.$("#rfidContainer").val();
        //the magic..
    }
});
```

***HTML:***

```
<div  id="results">
   <input id="rfidContainer"/> 
</div>
<div class="footer-btn confirm td-div">
   <img src="img/done.png" /> F1 - Confirm
</div>
```

Comment: If the input is not visible I can not focus on it to capture any input